# Spring Boot + Yaml + @PropertySource + @ConfigurationProperties + List in Property Source file not injecting

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to inject `external.yml` properties into a POJO using `@ConfigurationProperties` and importing my `external.yml` file using `@PropertySource`. All other were injected into POJO but not a complex list.

a. I tried using `@NestedConfigurationProperty` for the complex list and map.
b. I tried complex POJO as inner static and outer class.
c. Tried `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation. etc

```java
ExternalProp.java

   @Component
   @PropertySource(value = "classpath:external.yml", encoding = "UTF-8")
   @ConfigurationProperties

   @Data
   public class ExternalProp {

    private String bla;
    private List<Person> persons;
    private List<String> other;

    @Data
    public static class Person {

        private int age;
        private String name;
        private Map<String, String> args;
    }

}
```

```
external.yml

   bla: bkdfjgkdf
   persons:
   -  age: 12
      name: bla1
      args:
        a0: a0dev
        a1: a1dev
        a2: a2dev
   -  age: 12
      name: bla2
      args:
        b0: b0dev
        b1: b1dev
        b2: b2dev
   strings: bla, bla1
```

`bla: bkdfjgkdf` and `strings: bla, bla1` have been injected properly but not persons. Where am I making mistake.

And same `persons` object copied to `application.yml` file, then, BOOM, getting values properly.

I'm expecting a List of Persons which is having some Map `args`.

Comment: So the problem is when you use PropertySource right? It works if it is in application.yml without PropertySource

Comment: @vanillaSugar - yes. Other simple POJOs also not working.

Comment: I just verified, if it is external.properties instead of external.yml it is working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @PropertySource using YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml)

Comment: PropertySource does not support YAML

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thank you so much, after searching like hours this was my mistake

Answer (score -2):

I believe it has to do with your yml formatting.
try this

```
external.yml

   bla: bkdfjgkdf
   persons:
      -  age: 12
         name: bla1
         args:
           a0: a0dev
           a1: a1dev
           a2: a2dev
      -  age: 12
         name: bla2
         args:
           b0: b0dev
           b1: b1dev
           b2: b2dev
   strings: bla, bla1
```