# How to map complex types in YML file to java object by using Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

Have the list of complex objects in YML format:

```
Messages: 
  error1: 
    code: 0988
    text: "error message1"
  error2: 
    code: 0988
    text: "error message2"
```

I need to map this structure to java class:

```
public class MessageProvider {
    private Message error1;
    private Message error2;
    //getters, setters

    public static class Message{
        private String text;
        private String code;
        //getters, setters
    }
}
```

Is it possible to map it by using spring boot capabilities ? If yes, I will be thankful for example.

Comment: The example is shown in a related (tab on the right) question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40153935/3080094 A little bit more searching might help next time.

Comment: in the link you provided is list of elements but it is not about what i'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the this [Yaml Tutorial](http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/) this is how to suppose to deserialize a `yaml` file:

```
YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader("your-yaml.yml"));
Object object = reader.read();
System.out.println(object);
MessageProvider map = (MessageProvider)object;
System.out.println(map.get("error1"));
```