# Spring - @Pattern regexp value from YAML file. (Javax | Hibernate)

Tags: regex, spring, hibernate, yaml, javax.validation

Trying to read regex values from yaml file in POJO class. like this,

```
@Pattern(regexp = "${something.value}")
private String someValue;
```

But this is not working because its expecting below, (Within annotations you can only refer to constant expressions)

```
Pattern.regexp must be a constant expression at run time.
```

Am curious if there is any solution for this case with only supporting Annotations or calling some get/set methods at runtime which holds value of config.

Not really looking for custom validator solution though.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this the same thing ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591861/dynamic-pojo-validation-based-on-groups-in-spring

Comment: @Maxt8r not really with Strategy Pattern .. Looking for annotation with reading capabilities from yaml.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. That @Pattern annotation is evaluated at compile time.
While the values from the YAML file is evaluated at run time.