# Mapping List in YAML file to List of objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to inject list in my application.yml file to list of objects Java in my Spring Boot application.

I have seen some answers to others similar questions [Mapping list in Yaml to list of objects in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593014/mapping-list-in-yaml-to-list-of-objects-in-spring-boot) but I have differents output errors.

My YAML file

```
s3tool:
   buckets:
     -
      name: myentity1
      accessKey: access
      secretKey: secret
      endpoint: endepoint
      proxyPort: 3128
      proxyHost: gateway-address
     -
      name: myentity2
      accessKey: access
      secretKey: secret
      endpoint: endepoint
      proxyPort: 3128
      proxyHost: gateway-address
```

I have also created Bucket class

```
 public class Bucket {

       private String name;

       private String accessKey;

       private String secretKey;

       private String endpoint;

       private String proxyHost;

       private int proxyPort;

      //getters and setters
  }
```

And my configuration class where I inject the list in YAML

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    @ConfigurationProperties
    public class S3ClientHelper {

        @Value("${s3tool.buckets}")
        private List<Bucket> buckets;

   //others methods 
   }
```

When Spring Boot starts excuting I got the following error:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 's3tool.buckets' in value "${s3tool.buckets}"
```

I have also tried with simple list of String but I also got the similar error.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "s3tool")
public class S3ClientHelper {

    private List<Bucket> buckets;

  //others methods 
}
```

Comment: the list (buckets) stays null when I try this.

Comment: do you have getters ans setters for buckets?

Comment: In my class Bucket I have getters and setters, but not for the list buckets.

Comment: try adding getters and setters for buckets also. It should work

Comment: Create a constructor in your bucket class that takes each of the member variables.  IIRC, Spring will want to use constructor injection here.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock not necessary. I just tried out. getter/setters in both Bucket and S3ClientHelper classes are enough

Comment: @MichaelPeacock I had already a constructor in Bucket which takes each member variables.

Comment: @pvpkiran I tried what you said, but it's always the same error. I think that my Spring Application has problem to map list in YAML file. Event if I try with simple list of String I got the same error. But I can inject others simple attributes.