# How to read a list from a YAML file into Java using jackson?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jackson, yaml

So, I have a YAML file like this:

```
- code: QWERTY1
  name: qwerty-name
  desc: a qwerty desc
- code: QWERTY2
  name: qwerty-name-2
  desc: a qwerty desc 2
```

And I am trying to read this as list of `MyObject` using `jackson`.

My Java code looks like this:

```
public <T, K> List<K> readSerializedList(File f, Class<T> formatType, Class<K> classType) throws IOException{
    ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    try {
        final T result = MAPPER.readValue(f, formatType);
        List<K> myList = MAPPER.convertValue(result, new TypeReference<List<K>>() { });
        return myList;
    } catch (JsonParseException | JsonMappingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } 
}
```

and I call it from another function like this:

```
readSerializedList(new File("path/to/file/a.yaml"), List.class, MyObject.class)
```

Instead of obtaining a list of `MyObject`, I obtain a `LinkedHashMap`.

If I explicitly change line 4 to :

```
List<MyObject> myList = MAPPER.convertValue(result, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>() { });
```

then I obtain a list of `MyObject`.

I need that kind of generalization that I'm trying to achieve because the design is such that, `readSerializedList()` should be able to read from YAML any kind of list we tell it to.

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm using Springboot with Java 8.

Comment: But any reason why you want to read yml urself. springboot is capable of converting your yml to object list. You can do this using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: @pvpkiran Could you illustrate it with a small example?

Comment: have a look at this question and my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837283/mapping-list-in-yaml-file-to-list-of-objects/50837946?noredirect=1#comment88682164_50837946

Comment: This looks great! But where do you specify which YAML file to read from? And where from do you obtain the list object?

Comment: create a file by name application.yml under resources folder. Rest will be taken care by springboot. Do upvote if that answer helped.

Comment: I cannot do that, i have to read from specific files every time. I specify each time which file to read from. Adding `@Configuration` & `@ConfigurationProperties` hasn't helped at all

Comment: tra with `@ImportResource`