# create yml with keysValues

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a .yml in my Springboot, I am trying create an array in my .yml with a class java (key/value), but I get error when I execute the app.

Yml:

```
profiles: 
 - type: user
   url:  www
 - type: admin
   url:  http
```

Then I get datas in my implements using my class Profile:

```
@Value("${profiles}")
private List<Profile> profiles;
```

Finally my class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {
    private String type;
    private String url;
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'api': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'profiles' in value "${profiles}"
```

I want read my yml for check values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.profiles.size(); i++) {
        Profile pr = this.profiles.get(i);
        System.out.println(pr.getType() + pr.getUrl());
    }
```

Please I need help, I search in google but only get "Arrays" `['1','2','3']` o two Arrays ... 
I need a structure the key/value

```
profiles: [
 {
    'key':'user',
    'url': 'www'
 },
 {
   'key':'admin',
   'url': 'http'
 }
]
```

Ahh !! My profiles can have 2,4, 1000 registros... that's why I pick it up List

```
   @Value("${profiles}")
    private List<Profile> profiles;
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604427/1776132?

Comment: Could you provide your application main entry point and configuration?

Comment: @tmarwen I only read the yml.

Comment: @Smile perfect ty !!