# Accessing Complex Arrays: Type-safe Configuration Properties in Spring-boot YAML File

Tags: spring, list, spring-boot, yaml, application.properties

Please consider my `Application.YAML` file.

```
name-change:
  - original-name: mango
    changed-name: mangifera
  - original-name: coconut
    changed-name: cocos
```

I want to access this configs in the spring-boot application/ `RestController`.

```
@Value("${name-change[0].original-name}")
private String origianlName;
```

The above code works perfectly fine.

But **failed** **to cast/convert** the following configs in to a List.
Eg:

```
@Value("${name-change}")
private List<Object> changedNames;
```

OR,

```
@Value("${name-change}")
private List<ChangedName> changedNames;
```

where, `ChangedName` is a POJO class.

Please help me to bind configs in `YAML` file to a Java List(`List<ChangedName> changedNames`).

Answer (score 0):

I found this article:

[Mapping list in Yaml to list of objects in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593014/mapping-list-in-yaml-to-list-of-objects-in-spring-boot?rq=1)

It has a similar example and it worked for me.