# Why can't I inject one of my PoJo's with Spring's @Value annotation?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In Spring I can configure all kinds of objects like int, boolean, String, etc. with the @Value injection.
I even can configure a whole map structure with a single @Value injection.

Let's assume we have the following TCP server specification class:

```
public class TcpServerSpec {

    private boolean enabled;
    private String host;
    private int port;

    /* getters & setters */
}
```

I could inject a map of several server specifications by their names, doing ...

```
@Value("${com.harry.potter.sockets}")
private HashMap<String, TcpServerSpec> sockets;
```

... with the following YAML configuration (application-test1.yml):

```
com:
  harry:
    potter:
      sockets:
        server1:
          enabled: true
          host: host1
          port: 1111
        server2:
          enabled: true
          host: host2
          port: 2222
```

But often one needs something in between: the injection of just one TcpServerSpec:

```
@Value("${com.harry.potter.sockets.server1}")
private TcpServerSpec server1;
```

Then I could pass sucessfully the following tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ConfigurationProperties("com.harry.potter.sockets")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test1.yml")
public class MyServerConfiguration1Test {

    @Value("${com.harry.potter.sockets.server1}")
    private TcpServerSpec server1;

    @Value("${com.harry.potter.sockets.server2}")
    private TcpServerSpec server2;

    @Test
    public void testServer1Spec() {
        Assert.assertTrue(server1.isEnabled());
        Assert.assertThat(server1.getHost(), is("host1"));
        Assert.assertThat(server1.getPort(), is(1111));
    }

    @Test
    public void testServer2Spec() {
        Assert.assertTrue(server2.isEnabled());
        Assert.assertThat(server2.getHost(), is("host2"));
        Assert.assertThat(server2.getPort(), is(2222));
    }
}
```

Why is this not possible?
Or is it?

Comment: After some testing I do believe that the injection of a map is a bit more complicated than simply use the @Value annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want is not @Value but [@ConfigurationProperties](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot).

You can declare your beans manually like this:

```
@Configuration
class BeanConfig {
  
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.harry.potter.sockets.server1")
  public TcpServerSpec server1() {
    return new TcpServerSpec();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.harry.potter.sockets.server2")
  public TcpServerSpec server2() {
    return new TcpServerSpec();
  }
}
```

And then inject those beans with @Qualifier("server1") and @Qualifier("server2").

Comment: why do you have `@Bean` _and_ `@ConfigurationProperties`? and why `prefix`? I don't understand how this answers the question

Comment: You're right, `@Bean` is not needed when using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: After checking your answer: I think the \@Bean annotation is needed but the \@Qualifier is not. The two managed beans are found without any resolution problem because of their different names serer1/server2.

Comment: Great @JBStonehenge !! Rolling back the Bean annotation hehe My answer helped you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me but also raised another issue. Adding server3 would require a configurative change - in the yaml file - and a programmatic change - in your `BeanConfig` class.

Comment: If you want more dinamyc with lists, you could create a class `TcpServerList` annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.harry.potter.sockets")` and with a prop `List<TcpServerSpec> servers`. Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593014/mapping-list-in-yaml-to-list-of-objects-in-spring-boot).